# Regex to exclude results after dynamic part of URL

Tags: regex, matomo

I am setting heatmap tracking rules for Matomo analytics platform. The part of my URL will always be dynamic and contain only capital letters, for example - http://example.com/ASDFG. I can address this with `http:\/\/example\.com\/[A-Z]+`.

But it gets trickier to track the subdirectories, for example, http://example.com/ASDFG/page1 .

`http:\/\/example\.com\/[A-Z]+` will not only track http://example.com/ASDFG but also http://example.com/ASDFG/page1 .

Ideally, I am thinking of having two separate expressions:

- one for ignoring everything after the dynamic URL part, for example - http://example.com/ASDFG
- another one for matching a particular page name after the dynamic URL, for example - http://example.com/ASDFG/page1

No need to match the `www` parameter as it gets prepended by the analytics platform automatically.

What would be the best way to write these two expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe,

```
^https?:\/\/example\.com\/[A-Z]+\/?$
^http:\/\/example\.com\/[A-Z]+\/?$
```

or without final slashes,

```
^https?:\/\/example\.com\/[A-Z]+$
^http:\/\/example\.com\/[A-Z]+$
```

might be desired for the first one.

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/BA5bUJ/1/)

---

For the second one, it would be as simple as,

```
^https?:\/\/example\.com\/[A-Z]+\/(?:page1|page2|page3)\/?$
^http:\/\/example\.com\/[A-Z]+\/(?:page1|page2|page3)\/?$
```

for multiple pages, and

```
^https?:\/\/example\.com\/[A-Z]+\/page1\/?$
^https?:\/\/example\.com\/[A-Z]+\/page2\/?$
^https?:\/\/example\.com\/[A-Z]+\/page3\/?$
```

for one by one page.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/oFYc2T/1/)

> You can also remove the `\/?` at the end, if it'd be unnecessary, and
>   similarly `s?` if `https` is not required.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/TGc3Wt/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/TGc3Wt/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick input! You have combined both of the cases into one expression. I think I need to have two separate expressions one for ignoring everything after the dynamic URL part and another for including the first subdirectory after the dynamic URL. Let me edit the question to reflect all of this.

Comment: Yes, I think it should work. Is it just a matter of adding the page name to the end of it  to match the second case like so - `^https?:\/\/example\.com\/[A-Z]+\/?page1\/?$`?

Comment: I have multiple pages, but I will be tracking a heatmap of each page separately. That's why I think I need to match the exact name of the page, not just  the range of lowercase letters and numbers - `[a-z0-9]`. I really appreciate your help. Can you please add the links from comments to your answer? I will then accept it.

Comment: sure, I'm waiting for the analytics platform support to get back to me on the reason why valid regex does not work on their side. Once I get any reply, I will accept your answer. If it takes to long I will accept anyways as regex validators show that the provided expressions are correct.